Unable to access attribute of a custom data model
I am trying to pass custom list data to the target screen. Screenshots of the code are provided below.
The first screenshot shows how I pass the custom data model to the target screen, the second screenshot shows an example of how I am creating the List to pass to the target screen, and the third screenshot shows the error that I am getting.
1.(https://i.sstatic.net/wqb6JeY8.png)
2.(https://i.sstatic.net/zqpqtk5n.png)
3.(https://i.sstatic.net/wSBGuiY8.png)

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If the error you are referring to is on the DetailsScreen.dart at line 33 then it is not an issue of passing data to the target screen. It is that you are trying to access a field of DetailModel in a list of DetailModel types without providing an index of which one you'd like to access. To quickly solve the error try:
SizedBox(
  width: 500,
  height: 200,
  child: Image.asset(modern[0].imageurl),
)

Now this is likely not what you want to do but it helps you see the problem that you are facing. The [0] is accessing the index in the first position of the list.
You may want to wrap those SizedBoxes in a Listview.builder to enumerate all of the DetailModel types in your modern. Let me know if you have any questions.

can you show me with code

Are you referring to the code of the ListView?
